# Edit YAML frontmatter in org-mode blog post destined for Jekyll

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to use emacs' org-mode to write blog posts for my Jekyll-driven blog. Reading [Using org to Blog with Jekyll](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-jekyll.html), what is normally done is to put your front matter in an `#+BEGIN_HTML` / `#+END_HTML` block which passes the front matter through untouched.

However, using `org-edit-special` (`C-c '`), you end up with `html-mode` in the special edit buffer. Switching to `yaml-mode` doesn't work, because you can't go back from the special edit mode.

Is there some way to be able to edit this front matter in `yaml-mode` without resorting to things like changing the whole buffer to `yaml-mode` then back to `org-mode` ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I came up with:

Creating a babel execute function for yaml:

```
(defun org-babel-execute:yaml (body params) body)
```

Then I can do what I'd like:

```
#+STARTUP: showall expand
#+options: toc:nil
#+begin_src yaml :exports results :results value html
  ---
  layout: post
  title: test post with yaml source block frontmatter
  gallery:
    path: abc123
    images:
      - blah.png
      - bloo.png
  ---
#+end_src

* hello world
```

And this produces exactly what I want in the markdown file when I export it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom command where html is associated with yaml-mode.

```
(defun org-edit-html-export-block-as-yaml ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-src-lang-modes '(("html" . yaml))))
    (org-edit-export-block)))

(define-key org-mode-map YOUR-KEY 'org-edit-html-export-block-as-yaml)
```

I've tested this (with the developmental version of Org mode) on

```
#+begin_html
key: 3
#+end_html
```

and it seems to work fine.